# Why updaing a MobX observable property doesn't work when passed as a reference

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm experimenting with MobX, and would like to understand a basic thing regarding an observable update.

In the following code, `store.parentState.counter` is passed from `Parent` to `Child`. Both `Parent` and `Child` have an `increment` button that's supposed to update `counter`.

However, only `Parent`'s button updates the counter.

Why is that? Also, can we make the child button work?

```
import React from "react";
import { observable, configure } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

const store = observable({
  parentState: {
    counter: 0
  }
})
const Parent = observer((props) => {
  const increment = () => { store.parentState.counter += 1; };
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Parent: {store.parentState.counter}</span>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
      <Child parentCounter={store.parentState.counter} />
    </div>
  );
});
const Child = observer(({parentCounter}) => {
  const increment = () => { parentCounter +=1 ; };
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Child</span>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
});

configure({
  enforceActions: "never",
})

export default Parent;
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-elbakyan-q4c3u).

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I'm aware that with this example, the child can simply update the store directly, so that passing a reference to `counter` doesn't make much sense. Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, the child can be passed the `store`.
*But*, as mentioned, I'm experimenting with MobX, and would like to understand the *Why* (and whether it can be made to work).

Comment: If parent and child components are in differents files try passing the store <Child parentCounter={store} />

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]**: You are passing the `counter` directly in the prop. I assume that since it's a primitive, it is passed as value (Instead of ref as for objects) and therefore does not have any bind to the store. Passing the `appState` node works well as shown in [this Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-cbh5rm?file=index.js). Here is the code just in case :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";

const store = observable({
  appState: {
    counter: 0
  }
});

const App = observer(() => {
  const increment = () => (store.appState.counter += 1);

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: {store.appState.counter}
      <br />
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <hr />
      <AppChild appState={store.appState} />
    </div>
  );
});

const AppChild = observer(({ appState }) => {
  const increment = () => (appState.counter += 1);
  return (
    <>
      Counter: {store.appState.counter}
      <br />
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment from child</button>
    </>
  );
});

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

I don't know MobX but since your store is global, as in other store manager, it makes no sense to pass a value from your parent to a component wrapped with `observer()`. just doing as follow works :

```
import React from "react";
import { observable, configure } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"; // 6.x or mobx-react-lite@1.4.0
import "./styles.css";

const store = observable({
  parentState: {
    counter: 0
  }
});
const Parent = observer((props) => {
  const increment = () => {
    store.parentState.counter += 1;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Parent: {store.parentState.counter}</span>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
      <Child parentCounter={store.parentState.counter} />
      <Child2 updateCounter={increment} />
    </div>
  );
});

const Child = observer(() => {
  const increment = () => {
    console.log(store.parentState.counter);
    store.parentState.counter += 1;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Child</span>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
});

const Child2 = ({updateCounter}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Child2</span>
      <button onClick={updateCounter}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

configure({
  enforceActions: "never"
});

export default Parent;
```

I added a Child2 component to show you how you could do it by using a parent method to update your store through a component that is not wrapped with `observer()`.

Now, since it makes no sense to me, there might be a solution to do it I don't know, but I don't see any case where you need to do that.

Comment: I know it makes no sense (though maybe should've clarified that). Just want to know why it happens, and can we make it work.

Comment: @OfirD I edited my answer to give you what I'm pretty sure is the anwser to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [MobX documentation](https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html): **MobX tracks property access, not values.**

> > MobX reacts to any existing observable property that is read during
> > the execution of a tracked function.
>
> - *"reading"* is dereferencing an object's property, which can be done
>   through "dotting into" it (eg. `user.name`) or using the bracket
>   notation (eg. `user['name']`, `todos[3]`).
> - *"tracked functions"* are the
>   expression of `computed`, the *rendering* of an `observer` React function
>   component, the `render()` method of an `observer` based React class
>   component, and the functions that are passed as the first param to
>   `autorun`, `reaction` and `when`.
> - *"during"* means that only those observables
>   that are read while the function is executing are tracked. It doesn't
>   matter whether these values are used directly or indirectly by the
>   tracked function. But things that have been 'spawned' from the
>   function won't be tracked (e.g. `setTimeout`, `promise.then`, `await` etc).
>
> In other words, MobX will not react to:
>
> - Values that are obtained from observables, but outside a tracked
>   function
> - Observables that are read in an asynchronously invoked code
>   block

Hence, passing `store.parentState` and accessing `counter` in the child will make it work.